# Iterating through rows SQL + Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with many columns and rows, and there are groups under one column and people under another, and every group can have 1 or more people inside it. I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if there is more than one instance of that group showing up:
    iterate through it and count how many members in that group have family members, then insert into a table
else:
    just take out that member and count how many family members he has and insert into a table
```

I come from a python background and SQL still is very new to me, but my (VERY BUGGY) attempt:

```
if (select count(groupname) from table group by groupname) > 1 
then _________
else
insert___ into ___
```

Table A looks a little like this:

```
groups                   people
A                        tom
A                        jerry
B                        sarah
```

Table B looks like this:

```
person                   familyMembers
tom                        daughter
tom                        son
tom                        wife
sarah                      husband
```

where tom has 3 family members, sarah only has 1

Kind of lost, insights?

Comment: Are you looking for help in MySQL, or in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Will both cases insert into the same table, or do they need to insert into different tables?

Comment: @sammuh Can you add the table structure with sample data for more clarity?

Comment: They will be inserted into the same table.

Comment: is people in table A a foreign key to person in table B?

Comment: @ivan7707 no it isnt

Comment: your pseudocode is difficult to understand.  I'd say rework it first to simplify it put it on more lines.  @Dan is a total champ for even trying to answer the question considering the info you have provided.  Maybe comment on whether that worked for you and if not, why not.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear how the group plays into this. It sounds like you want a count of the number of family members for each person, correct? A simple way would be to just count the family in tableB:

```
SELECT
  person,
  COUNT(familyMembers) AS count_familyMembers
FROM tableB
GROUP BY person
```

This ignores the "`group`" column all together, but will miss anyone if they don't have a record in tableB (such as Jerry in your example).

To include Jerry, you'll need to do the following. This will check if familyMembers is `NULL` and return 0, otherwise will return 1. It then sums all of those up, so you get a total number of records, split up by the groups and people columns.

```
SELECT
  groups,
  people,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN familyMembers IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END) AS count_familyMembers
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
  ON tableA.people = tableB.person
GROUP BY groups,
         people
```

If the above works, you can then add an "`INTO`" to create a new table:

```
SELECT
  groups,
  people,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN familyMembers IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END) AS count_familyMembers INTO new_table
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
  ON tableA.people = tableB.person
GROUP BY groups,
         people
```

or an "`INSERT INTO`" for an existing table. If you do "`INSERT INTO`", you'll need to match the data and columns up:

```
INSERT INTO existingTable (groups, people, familyCount)
  SELECT
    groups,
    people,
    SUM(CASE
      WHEN familyMembers IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END) AS count_familyMembers INTO new_table
  FROM tableA
  LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.people = tableB.person
  GROUP BY groups,
           people
```